# Assigning value to variable when IF statement is false causes error in Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a function in Python that should search a string for a substring, then assign the index of the substring to a variable. And if the substring isn't found, I'd like to assign -1 to the variable to be used as a stop code elsewhere.  But I get an error that I don't understand.  Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
test = "abc"
search_str = "z"
index_search_str = test.index(search_str) if search_str in test else index_search_str = -1
```

If I run this code, the value of `index_search_str` should be -1, but instead I get this error (using PyCharm):

```
 index_search_str = test.index(search_str) if search_str in test else index_search_str = -1
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Maybe you meant '==' or ':=' instead of '='?
```

But if I change `= -1` to `:= -1`, it still gives an error.  What am I missing?

Comment: You got your ternary operator wrong. the assignment only happens at the start, not in the "else". Corrected version: ``index_search_str = test.index(search_str) if search_str in test else -1``

Comment: The real question is, why are you not just using `index_search_str = test.find(search_str)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, in using ternary operator, value should be returned.

```
test = "azbc"
search_str = "z"
index_search_str = test.index(search_str) if search_str in test else -1

print(index_search_str)    # print value maybe  "1"
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot assign variable in one-line statement

```
test = "abc"
search_str = "z"
index_search_str = test.index(search_str) if search_str in test else -1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code have syntax errors.

I think you need something like this:

```
test = "abc"
search_str = "z"
if search_str in test:
    print("match")
    index_search_str = test.index(search_str)
    print(index_search_str)
else :
    print("not match")
    index_search_str = -1
    print(index_search_str)
```

"not match"
"-1"

```
test = "abc"
search_str = "c"
if search_str in test:
    print("match")
    index_search_str = test.index(search_str)
    print(index_search_str)
else :
    print("not match")
    index_search_str = -1
    print(index_search_str)
```

match
2

Answer (score 1):

Just use `str.find` instead... it does exactly what you're trying to do by default.

```
>>> test = "abc"
>>> print(test.find('z'))
-1

>>> print(test.find('b'))
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

> index_search_str = test.index(search_str) if search_str in test else -1